# send plain text by iMessage applescript failed

Tags: imessage

```
tell application "Messages"
  set myid to get id of first service
  set theBuddy to buddy "18659282917" of service id myid
  send "this is a imessage`s text" to theBuddy
end tell
```

I run the script, but it got the error:

> error number -1728 from buddy id
>   "8A63A596-FD3C-47ED-88DF-E13E41023F34:+8618659282917"

But i can send message to the buddy "18659282917" by iPod and iPhone.
 What is wrong?